# Plugin extension name clash with task name

Tags: gradle, plantuml, gradle-task

I have a plugin that has same name for its plugin extension and for task name (both are named `plantUml`).

I would like to run task before build. How can I do that?

When I type:

```
build dependsOn: plantUml
```

then I get information that it cannot be applied to plugin extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to reference tasks via their names in methods like `dependsOn` and `finalizedBy`. This should be possible in both the Groovy and the Kotlin syntax:

```
build.dependsOn 'plantUml'
```

Tasks can also be referenced via the [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html). The method `getAt(...)` provides a task based on its name. This method gets mapped to the array syntax in Groovy:

```
build.dependsOn tasks['plantUml']
```